# Avoid $ conflict with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, conflict

I am pretty sure this must have been asked in another form, but searching for the $ sign does not yield any results here.

I have already made a big system, and used jQuery extensively, referencing it with the $. At this point, I don't want to go back.

My problem is that now I have implemented CKEditor, which also references itself with the $, like many other JavaScript frameworks. So now I get a conflict and lots of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cannot get property 'any_function' of undefined
```

I don't want to go through the CKEditor code, searching and replacing, since I will be updating in the future. I also want to keep using $ for jQuery, but nothing else.

Off course I cannot simply use:

```
$.noConflict()
```

Without breaking my scripts.

Is there a way where I can keep using $ for jQuery whenever I want, while letting my JavaScript frameworks use $ internally?

What is my best/easiest solution here?

Comment: Have you looked for a version that works with JQuery? I know TinyMCE has this.

Comment: The documentation for CKEditor shows it using a global called `CKEDITOR`, not `$`. Are you sure you are looking at the right source of your variable?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, Quentin. But the CKEditor script uses $ internally as well.

Comment: Twisty, CKEditor is copmattible with jQuery, if you just format your code correctly from the start, making sure jQuery does not conflict with other scripts. I just haven't done that, so now I must find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap either sets of your code in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and pass the relevant object to it.

```
(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

I'd also suggest assigning CKEditor to something else right after it's been loaded so that you can follow a similar pattern for CKEditor code.

```
// Right after loading CKEditor
var CKEditor = $;

// Code that uses CKEditor
(function($) {
   ...
})(CKEditor);
```

Although it'd be more sustainable to just reassign CKEditor to another variable and only use that variable.

Comment: Well, the problem is that jQuery is sprinkled all over the system, and I want to be able to use the $ for only this. CKEditor is assigned to the CKEDITOR variable when called outside its own library, but uses the $ internally. This is what causes the conflicts. I will try wrapping CKEditor in a scoped function.

Comment: @Pjottur For what it's worth, I'm looking at the source of CKEditor right now and I don't see it referencing `$` anywhere inside. Maybe you have an older version or something or you might be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: This would off course solve my problem. But since this should be a common problem, it might be nice if there was some smart solution to this.

Comment: @Pjottur I wouldn't say this is a very common problem. jQuery has `.noConflict` for a reason. The "smart" solution would be to either use a version of CKEditor that doesn't reference `$` or to rework your code to work with `.noConflict`.

Comment: I have run into this problem before, but always at a stage where I could easily rework the code for it. I would gues that this ought to happen quite often, since I can't be the only one who failed to *ahem* plan ahead for this... I just have a feeling there should be a simple way to play with the scope somehow and be able to use this as it is, since I will probably find myself in the same mess again sometime in the future...

Comment: @Pjottur The only way to "play with the scope" is the way I've mentioned here.